# EpiServer Optimizely v12 - TinyMce - TinyMceSpellChecker - Add Disctionary

Tags: tinymce, spell-checking, episerver, optimizely

I have followed all the guides and tried many combinations , but I am still getting a js alert that the en-GB.aff file is missing whenever I try using en-GB.

What is the exact path to a new dictionary , for example Ive tried placing it here :

PROJECT\modules_protected\EPiServer.TinyMCESpellChecker\Dictionaries\en-GB\en-GB.aff

I tried everything in the guide

https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/integrations/v1.1.0-apps-and-integrations/docs/optimizely-spellchecker-for-tinymce

**UPDATE / FIX**
Optimizely fixed this from v3.0.1
https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/Release-Notes/ReleaseNote/?releaseNoteId=SPELLCHECK-36

Comment: Tried to update EPiServer.TinyMCESpellChecker to 3.0.1? 
https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/Release-Notes/ReleaseNote/?releaseNoteId=SPELLCHECK-36

Comment: Yes that was Optimizely's suggestion thanks , that wasn't an option when I posted this question and the bug was not set a public then... but it looks like the fix we've been waiting for thanks !